# What IP address do I assign in order to keep communication between my AP and my router?

Tags: networking, router, dhcp, vlan

My network setup:

WAN > Router(pfsense) > AP(tomato)

The gateway for my router is 10.12.1.1

The gateway for my AP is 10.12.1.201

My AP is only an AP, not a DHCP server. The router is my DHCP server.

What I'm trying to do is create a new bridge(br1) on my AP, to assign it to a VLAN. Well I need to give br1 an IP address.

On br0, my IP is 10.12.1.201.

I tried to assign br1 an IP of 10.12.2.201, and when I try to access my guest wifi (which is linked to the VLAN using br1), I have no internet connection. So I'm guessing anything on br1 can't communicate with my router.

Here's some pictures:

[image]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSTsB.png]

*edit: That screenshot shows 10.12.1.202

Well first I tried 10.12.2.201 and that didnt work so then I tried 10.12.1.202 and that didnt work either.

Answer (score 0):

The router and the AP has to be on the same subnet.
On your subnet mask (255.255.255.0) you can use the following range of ip addresses on the router:
`br0 10.12.1.1 - 10.12.1.254`
`br1 10.12.2.1 - 10.12.2.254`

Basically you need to create both br0 and br1 on your router, and assign your AP to br1

**Note:**
You need to enable DHCP on your router for br1 as well.
The IP address of the AP must not be in the DHCP range of your router.
Make sure the default gateway and DNS are set to the routers IP address.

Comment: I'm guessing it was a typo when you said br1 is 10.12.2.1-10.12.1.254 right?

Comment: @jobied - sorry, edited.